# Occurrence of a value

Tags: excel

In Excel, I am trying to create a formula to count the number of times a value occurs in an [array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeJly.png) of values. I have tried using the countif function, but unfortunately, I don't think it can count for a table. My current formula is `=countif(A3: B6,"=H9")` The `A3:B6` is my array of values, and `"=H9"` is my criteria. Is there anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value you want to count is stored in the call H9 then use.

```
=countif(A3:B6,H9)
```

You don't need the equals as it assumes you want it to equal the value unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Even if it was a greater than or less than comparison, the syntax would be `">" & H9` or `"<" & H9`.

Comment: @Gordon, do I need to omit the equals?